# Wordpress query / get template part

Tags: php, wordpress

I've searched and searched, but basically what I'm trying to do is this:

I have a custom post type where there is a custom field called "loop".  What I would like to do is when this field is filled out, I want to use it's content as a template part.  So, for instance:

Custom Field Loop:  customloop

get_template_part( 'customloop')

So, when I run my query for this post, I basically need whatever's filled out in that custom field to then be thrown into the get_template_part() so that it pulls that particular loop.

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can do this with the [get_post_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) function, just make sure to use the correct key name.

```
$loop = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'customloop', true );
if($loop):
  get_template_part('customloop');
else:
  get_template_part('loop');
endif;
```